# Sending multiple images from client to Server

Tags: java, multithreading

How can we determine that one image ends and another one starts?
I am taking screenshots and sending it to server.
My code is sending only 1st screenshot to server.

**Client:**

Thread 1 is taking Screenshtot
Thread 2 is sending screen shot to server.

**Thread 2**

```
Thread sendingScreenShotThread = new Thread () {
    public void run () {
        //Sending Screen to Server
        try {
            ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", baos);
            ImageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            dos.write(ImageInBytes);
            File Rif = new File(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", Rif);
            System.out.println("thread2 is running...");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        finally{

            try {
                baos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }          
    }
};
```

**Server:**

```
try{   
    boolean processing=true;

    while(processing)
    {
        try {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
            while ((in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buffer);
                System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }finally {
            processing=false;
            if (out != null) out.close();
        }
    }
}
finally{
    out.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serversock.close();
}
```

Comment: show how you create "in" the InputStream in your server

Comment: You can't without sending meta-information (e.g. header with data-length preceding every image).

Comment: Use HTTP for this. One PUT call per image. You can include image metadata as HTTP headers.